# $\sum^{2n}_{k=0} \binom{2n}{k} \int_C \frac{z^{2k-2n}}{z} dz$ - Cauchy theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have to compute $\int_C(z+\frac{1}{z})^{2n}\frac{1}{z}dz$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $C$ is the unit circle with positive orientation.

How could I compute $\sum^{2n}_{k=0} \binom{2n}{k} \int_C \frac{z^{2k-2n}}{z} dz$? Do I use the Cauchy theorem?

Comment: This looks quite similar to your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693802/cauchys-theorem-for-contour-integration (for which you got and accepted an answer). Can you clarify what makes this question different?

Comment: I don't doubt the validity of the answer of Dr. MV, but it involves the theory that I have not seen in class. So I decided to create a more specific question so that I can answer that is satisfactory to my level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\int_C(z+\frac{1}{z})^{2n}\frac{1}{z}dz = \int_C \frac{(z^2+1)^{2n}}{z^{2n+1}}dz = \frac{2i\pi}{(2n)!} \frac{\partial^{2n}((z^2+1)^{2n})}{\partial z^{2n}}|_{z=0},$$ by using Cauchy theorem for derivatives. Can you finish the computation ?

Comment: Well, you were right using binomial formula $(z^2+1)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} z^{2k}.$ The only term which won't give $0$ after $2n$ derivatives is $k=n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula see the formula for derivatives.

Comment: I understand my mistake, thanks!